# Regex combination

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible in regex to combine two validations?
Whenever  a series of 8 digit numbers(12345678) are given in a statement along with space(1234 5678)
Regex should throw an error. Along with validation for alphabets &other special character .

Eg: 1234 apartment ,#23building state 234 456 (valid one)

1234 apartment ,#23building state 1234  5678 overhill (invalid one because of series/continuous of 8 digits)

677 flat, @(23) floor, up state 56789123 state UK ( invalid because of continuous 8 digits)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. You need to clarify your question and add examples of input and expected output. More samples are needed for this. Also, what have *you* tried? Anyway, does `\b(?=[\d ]{9})\d+ \d+\b` do what you want? I'm not sure this is an *answerable* question without more details being provided and fear it will be closed on your because it's [**unclear what you're asking**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ctwheels I think he's looking for this `"1234 5678 offshore some location".replaceAll("\\s+","").matches("[0-9]{8}[a-zA-Z0-9]*");`

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7J2PBt/1)

```
(?:\d *){8}
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/OFZKsS)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = "(?:\\d *){8}";
        final String[] strings = {
            "1234 offshore address1234 Some locations",
            "1234 5678 offshore some location"
        };

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for (String s: strings) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if(!matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
1234 offshore address1234 Some locations
1234 5678 offshore some location
```

#### Output

Below shows strings that don't match.

```
1234 offshore address1234 Some locations
```

---

### Explanation

`(?:\d *){8}` matches a digit followed by any number of spaces exactly 8 times